# How to change value of public data fields in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++ .I want to to change the value of public member data2. In the second cout statement why I am not getting 10.5 value?

```
class Test
{
  private:
  int data1;

public:
  float data2;
  void function1()
  {
    data1=2;
  }
  float function2()
  {
    data2=3.5;
    return data2;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj2;
  Test obj1;
  cout<<"value of public member data2 is "<< obj2.function2()<<endl;
  obj2.data2=10.5;
  cout<<"new value of data2 is " <<obj2.data2<<where as its previous value 
was obj2.function2()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You are always setting `data2` in that `function2()` before you return, what did you expect??

Comment: You are calling function2 in the second cout statement. The function changes the data2 value to 3.5 and returns this value which is then printed by cout.

Comment: sorry I have modified Cout statement. It should give 'new value of data2 is 10.5 whereas its previous value was 3.5' but is is giving 3.5 at both places

Comment: @rida What _previous value_?? You are changing `data2` with each call to that function. Also your code example doesn't compile. Post real code please, not bogus stuff.

Comment: The compiler isn't required to work from left to right when evaluating a statement, it could just as well start from the right, or in the middle. Apparently here it starts with the function call.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `cout << x << b()` The compiler can break this down into something looking more logically like:

```
auto t = b()
cout << x << t
```

If your x is changed by b() then the modified one is what will be used

Comment: This is actually the correct explanation of what happens. The order of evaluation of function parameters (or operator parameters) is unspecified and the compiler can use whatever order it likes.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks - I know my answer was a little short, but I was racing to answer it before it got closed (imho incorrectly)

Answer (score -1):

Inside funtion2, You are assigning value again:

```
float function2()
{
    data2=3.5;
    return data2;
}
```

Remove `data2=3.5;` from function2